# Vb.net check if a website its html contains a string twice

Tags: .net, vb.net, basic

This code works:

```
Me.WebBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("Gezien")
```

So if the website has the text on it it will return true

but i want it only to return true if the string "gezien" is found twice on the website

sincerely Rivaldo

Comment: Can you please brief on your question?

Comment: Basically i want to see if a the website contains the string and the amount of times it contains the string

Answer (score 0):

```
DIm count = Me.WebBrowser1.DocumentText.Count(f => f == "Gezien")
```

This line above should give you the count. You will have to add reference to Linq namespace, if your code doesn't use it.

Comment: Thank you bro but i really have no clue how to convert this to working vb.net code

Comment: Check the edit. Let me know if it works. If not, follow this method from MSDN. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/mt692776.aspx

Comment: I tried this: 

                Dim text As String = Me.WebBrowser1.DocumentText
                Dim searchTerm As String = "Controleer"
                Dim dataSource As String() = text.Split(New Char() {" ", ",", ".", ";", ":"},
                                                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                Dim matchQuery = From word In dataSource
                     Where word.ToLowerInvariant() = searchTerm.ToLowerInvariant()
                     Select word

                Dim count As Integer = matchQuery.Count()

                Label7.Text = count

Comment: but it keeps returning 0 even when the text is available

Comment: Use dotnetfiddle.net and paste your code there. That way, everyone can run it and see.

Comment: It is blocked in India, so I can't see. Anyway, use dotnetfiddle as that will allow you to play around with code rather than acting as a text dump.

Comment: Can you fix your fiddle to make sure it runs properly? Read this. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve 
Post the code that we can run, not something that requires us to rewrite completely. 

p.s. dotnetfiddle is a code editor, so you can create a complete program there. using it to just copy paste the code defeats the purpose. think of it as online visual studio.

Comment: @RietRiet If you can't be bothered to put effort in to solve your problem, why should anyone else?

Comment: @RietRiet in that case, shall we ask for payment for our services here? Because I don't see why else will someone help out if that's the response to expect.